# Override configuration of a GitLab CI/CD Component

Tags: gitlab-ci

If I have a [GitLab CI/CD Component](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/components/), is there a way to override configuration values? I'm specifically thinking of things like *needs* or *rules*. `spec:inputs` seems to be the only way to pass configuration information but it is very limited, only supporting strings, numbers and booleans. This is what I would like to do:

*templates/publish.yml*

```yaml
spec:
  inputs:
    job-name:
      default: Publish
    stage:
      default: Publish
    rules:
      default: []
    needs:
      default: []
---
$[[ inputs.job-name ]]:
  image: python:3.12.2-alpine3.19
  stage: $[[ inputs.stage ]]
  rules: $[[ inputs.rules ]]
  needs: $[[ inputs.needs ]]
  script:
    ...
```

*gitlab-ci.yml*

```yaml
include:
  - component: $CI_SERVER_HOST/components/publish@latest
    inputs:
      stage: Publish
      needs:
        - job: Build
      rules:
        if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

stages:
  - Build
  - Publish

Build:
  ...
```

I thought CI/CD Components were supposed to be a better way to reuse jobs but so far it seems much more restrictive than extending a hidden job. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show what your component looks like?

Comment: This example wouldn't work but it embodies what I'd expect to be able to do with a CI/CD component.

Comment: Yeah, it's true you wouldn't be able to do something like this. But I'm not sure how much value there is in specifying inputs that mirror the existing YAML specification -- you can always override properties after including the component. For example, just write `jobname:needs:` into your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. I think you _can_ use inputs to form parts of those fields though, like `needs: ["$[[ inputs.needs ]]"]` but as you say, the input types are limited. Though, many features are [planned](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7462) for the catalog, including improvements to this spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature I was looking for already exists just by overriding properties on the job after including the component as [sytech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747944/sytech) pointed out. This is what I was looking for

*templates/publish.yml*

```yaml
spec:
  inputs:
    job-name:
      default: Publish
    stage:
      default: Publish
---
$[[ inputs.job-name ]]:
  image: python:3.12.2-alpine3.19
  stage: $[[ inputs.stage ]]
  script:
    ...
```

*gitlab-ci.yml*

```yaml
include:
  - component: $CI_SERVER_HOST/components/publish/publish@~latest

Publish: # This is the included job
  needs: # Add needs
    - job: Build
  rules: # Add rules
    if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

stages:
  - Build
  - Publish

Build:
  ...
```